# Puppet: How to generate a dynamic dependency chain

Tags: puppet

First I get an array like this:

```
$myarray = [
 {name => resource_1, type => define_type1},
 {name => resource_2, type => define_type2, require => resource_1},
 {name => resource_3, type => define_type1, require => resource_2},
]
```

and I want to a generate a dynamic order chain depend on `$myarray` like this:

```
define_type1{'resource_1':
}

define_type2{'resource_2':
  require => Define_type1['resource1']
}

define_type1{'resource_3':
  require => Define_type2['resource2']
}
```

I use `create_resources` to create all resources, but `require => $instance['require']` just get `require => resource_1`, what puppet need is `require => Define_type1['resource1']`.

```
each($myarray) { |$instance| 

  if $instance['require']{
    $params = {
      "$instance" => { require => $instance['require'] }
    }

    create_resources($instance['type'], $params)
  }   
  else{
    $params = {
      "$instance" => { }
    }

    create_resources($instance['type'], $params)
  }   
}
```

I can only use `define type` because there may be more than one resources of same type.

Is there a way to do this?